# Why is this C# code not functioning as expected?

Tags: c#

This is a C# code to enter 10 names, sort them in ascending order and print them with the condition if either of the elements are "Nobody" or "Somebody" it should skip that name when printing. The issue with my code is that it doesn't skip those 2 mentioned words and prints them as well, I don't understand why.
Sample Input:
Ravi 
Somebody 
Tanvir 
Ramesh 
Nobody 
Ani
Nobody 
Vishwanath 
Somebody 
Nitin

Sample Output:
Ani
Nitin
Ramesh
Ravi
Tanvir
Vishwanath
﻿

```
using System;

using System.Collections;

namespace LearnCsharp
{
    class NamesWithArrayList
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Update the code below
            ArrayList alObj;
            alObj = new ArrayList();
            int max=10;
            string item="";
            for(int i=0;i<max;i++)
            {
                alObj.Add(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            alObj.Sort();
            foreach (string item1 in alObj)
            {
                if(alObj.Contains("Somebody")){}
                else if(alObj.Contains("Nobody")){}
                else
                    Console.WriteLine(item1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `alObj.Contains("Somebody")` the list contains this string. You probably intended to compare `item1` with this string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You're checking if the *list* contains `"Somebody"` each time rather than if the *current value* is `"Somebody"`.
2. `ArrayList` is essentially a collection of `object`s, so string comparison is not being used when calling `Contains`. It's instead using object reference comparison, and since your inputs are different objects that the string constants, the comparison always fails.

So a version which uses string comparisons would be:

```
foreach (string item1 in alObj)
{
    if(item1 == "Somebody"){}
    else if(item1 == "Nobody"){}
    else
        Console.WriteLine(item1);
}
```

which could be simplified as:

```
foreach (string item1 in alObj)
{
    if(item1 != "Somebody" && item1 != "Nobody")
        Console.WriteLine(item1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check '''item1''' if it is your searched string and you need to put some code for the if statement what your app should do than.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that on the `if(alObj.Contains("Somebody")){}` line you're asking if the original `alObj` `ArrayList` contains the string "Somebody".  Your `foreach` loop should be re-written as follows:

```
foreach (string item1 in alObj)
{
    if(item1 == "Somebody")
    {
    }
    else if (item1 == "Nobody")
    {
    }
    else
        Console.WriteLine(item1);
}
```

However this could be improved further by merging those the "Somebody" and "Nobody" cases into one:

```
foreach (string item1 in alObj)
{
    if(item1 == "Somebody" || item1 == "Nobody")
    {
        // Do nothing
    }
    else
        Console.WriteLine(item1);
}
```

Finally this is a bit weird looking, the real *intent* of the code is "Only output the item if its not equal to 'Somebody' and not equal to 'Nobody'", which is best expressed like so:

```
foreach (string item1 in alObj)
{
    if(item1 != "Somebody" && item1 != "Nobody")
        Console.WriteLine(item1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining it so well, I understood the problem now.

Answer (score 0):

In 2020 you don't need to use `ArrayList`. In fact the only reason it is still exists probably is backward compatibility. Use `List<string>`. If you do that, you can do this

```cs
using System.Linq;
myList.Where(x => x != "Nobody" && x != "Somebody")
      .Sort(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
      .ToList()
      .ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

Another interesting way is this

```cs
using System.Linq;
var checkList = new List<string>(){ "Nobody", "Somebody" };
myList.Except(checkList)
      .Sort(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
      .ToList()
      .ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

In this instance you work on the lever of 2 lists. You will retrieve only items that don't match.

Comment: Thanks! I still have a very basic understanding of C# so at this point i'm just trying to make my code work any way possible.

Comment: @RahulMehta Even though... you should understand that `ArrayList` is ancient slow technology and shouldn't be used. You should learn good habits from the start. You can do what you do with the `List` also.